# Need to fetch all the Elements by Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am developing a Script to fetch all the Elements from the page:

It is a Button available more than one on the same Page.

When I Try with FireBug / Firepath, I obtained:

```
Locate=//*[@id='divHotelRecord']/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/img
```

Same HTML tag present in the source Code as:

```
<div class="hotel_desc_row"><img src="../Images/bnt_select_room.gif" border="0" onclick="toggleDiv('divRoomDetails_330728');" /></div>
```

Also, When I try to fetch all the elements by the below Selenium Java Code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(Locate));
System.out.println("Number of Elements Found: " + elements.size());
```

The output of the Code produces me:
    Number of Elements Found: 0

Kindly, please suggest what needs to be changed or required some other logic to be build.

Comment: We're going to need more information.  What happens if you try `WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='divHotelRecord']/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/img"));`?  Is this an internal page, or can you post a link so we can examine the html directly?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with by passing the Xpath value in the Fuction - Results the same.

Comment: What if you try `findElement` instead of `findElements`?  Is there an exception thrown?  If so, what is the exception?

Comment: Since, many of the Elements have same xpath as `//*[@id='divHotelRecord']/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/img`. So, yes When tried with `findElement` selects any random Element from the page.

Comment: The last two lines of code look like Java, but the `Locate=...` line isn't valid Java (missing quotes). What is it intended to be?

Answer (score 0):

Chetan Gadodia

you have to mention the position of the button if there were duplicates.

syntax : driver.(byxpath("(//*['id=xxxxx'][position()=2]")).click();